# ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup full markup

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `ReactDOMServer` to generate a static site via the server side and it doesn't seem to like this component specifically the opening `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag. (see below)

I'm doing this as I'm trying to use React to fully render a page via the server-side for IE8 compatibility and eventually become an isomorphic app.

Is there a best practice on how to fully render static markup with React via the server-side (with inclusions of the opening html tags, etc.)?

```js
'use strict';

import React from 'react';

export default class Root extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
      <title>Hello World!</title>
      </head>
      <body>

      <h1>Hello World!</h1>

      </body>
      </html>
    );
  }

}
```

```js
let html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<Root />);
```

**Bonus:** Although a simple DOCTYPE is breaking it, eventually I'd like to add additional IE tags like below at the top.

```html
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="no-js ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="no-js ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="no-js ie ie8 lte9 lte8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="no-js ie ie9 lte9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll likely want to emit the `DOCTYPE` header outside of your React component and replace `<!DOCTYPE html>` with an `<html>` node. JSX isn't HTML and just maps your elements to a corresponding React.createElement() call, which doesn't make sense for a `DOCTYPE`.

Take a look at these for reference:

- [Emitting a DOCTYPE before rendering the component](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/c22755e52565f0bfc829d88d31cb92b9749b8145/src/server.js#L75-L76)

`res.send('<!doctype html>\n' + ReactDOM.renderToString(<Html />));`

- [An HTML component that handles tag generation](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/c22755e52565f0bfc829d88d31cb92b9749b8145/src/helpers/Html.js)

`render() {
   return (
     <html lang="en-us">
        <head></head>
        ...
     </html>)
}`